# Chunking a vector of strings

Tags: rust

I'm trying to chunk an vector of uneven length strings into a vector of even length strings. The laziest way I could think of doing this is to join the arguments into a string, convert the chars to a vector, and then use [`Vec::chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.chunks). Unfortunately, I'm running into issues trying to collect the chunks into strings.

```
let args: Vec<String> = ["123", "4", "56"].iter().map(|&s| s.into()).collect();

let result: Vec<String> = args
    .join(" ")
    .chars()
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .chunks(2)
    .map(|c| c.collect::<String>())
    .collect::<Vec<String>>();

assert_eq!(["12", "34", "56"], result);
```

Results in the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `collect` found for type `&[char]` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:9:20
  |
9 |         .map(|c| c.collect::<String>())
  |                    ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `&mut &[char] : std::iter::Iterator`
          `&mut [char] : std::iter::Iterator`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You weren't far off:

```rust
let result: Vec<String> = args
    .join("")
    .chars()
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .chunks(2)
    .map(|x| x.iter().cloned().collect())
    .collect();

println!("{:?}", result);
```

1. You probably don't want a space when joining them together.
2. You need to convert each chunk (which is a `&[char]`) into an iterator via `.iter()`. You then have to convert the iterated type from a `&char` to a `char` via `.cloned()`.

---

I might write this using [`Itertools::chunks`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks) though:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.8.0

fn main() {
    let args = ["123", "4", "56"];

    let together = args.iter().flat_map(|x| x.chars());

    let result: Vec<String> = together
        .chunks(2)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.collect())
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

`flat_map` avoids the need to create a `String`, it just chains one iterator to the next.

`Itertools::chunks` allows the programmer to not create an intermediate `Vec`. Instead, it has an internal vector that, IIRC, will only store up to `n` values in it before yielding a value. This way you are buffering a smaller amount of items.